# Should I call socket::connect() from a handler invoked by resolver::async_resolve()?

Tags: boost, asynchronous, boost-asio, asyncsocket

I'm using a wrapper class to represent a network connection. My implementation contains a method, called `async_connect()`, which resolves a host/service and connects to a related endpoint (if possible). Something like this:

```
void tcp::connection::async_connect(std::string const& host, std::string const& service,
    protocol_type tcp = protocol_type::v4())
{
    std::cout << "thread [" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "] tcp::connection::async_connect()" << std::endl;

    resolver(m_io_service).async_resolve(resolver::query(tcp, host, service),
        boost::bind(&connection::resolve_handler, this, _1, _2));
}
```

What I want to do know, is establishing the connection from the handler, invoked by the completion of the `async_resolve` method.

I'm not sure wheter the main thread or the a worker thread is used to invoke the handler. Thus, should I call `socket::connect()` (this would be the most sensible way if that code would be executed from a worker thread) or start an asynchronous operation again (`socket::async_connect()` - which should be used when executed by main thread).

```
void tcp::connection::resolve_handler(boost::system::error_code const& resolve_error,
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
{
    std::cout << "thread [" << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "] tcp::connection::resolve_handler()" << std::endl;

    if (!resolve_error)
    {
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        m_socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator, ec);
    }
}
```

I've observed - from console output - that my `resolve_handler` is called from a worker thread. So, is it okay to call `socket::connect()` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO it is good to stick to a *single* programming model when using asio.

You are free to use asio's synchronous (blocking) calls, where you call a number of methods (resolve, connect, etc) and each one blocks until the result or error is available.

However If you're using the asynchronous programming model, your main or calling thread is typically blocked on io_service::run and the specified handlers are called from a different thread ( as is the case in what you described). When using this programming model you would typically call the next *async* method from the handler (worker thread), so instead of calling socket::connect, you would call socket::async_connect. It looks to me like you are trying to mix the two different models. I'm not sure what the implications are of mixing the two models (with your calling thread blocked on io_service::run) and you calling a synchronous method from the handler.

Comment: Hum, the handler is called from a worker thread. So, why do I need to queue another operation (by using `async_connect`) instead of executing it straight away. I thought this should be reasonable.

Comment: That is how you use asio asynchronously: async_connect is the non-blocking version meaning that the OS will notify you (via the handler) once the operation (e.g. connect, read, etc.) is complete. These operations might take arbitrarily long depending on e.g. the network, etc. In the meantime, the worker thread can handle other operations. The examples illustrate the different ways of using asio: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp